# Is this equal? (A == B if C == D)

Tags: math

A == B if C == D
C == D if A == B

Does A == B?

Comment: You'd need to know something about C==D to tell, all you have now is an equivalence.

Comment: @belisarius: Actually, I was in two minds, since it can be answered using Mathematica: `LogicalExpand[Implies[c == d, a == b] && Implies[a == b, c == d]]` returns `(b==a && d==c) || (b!=a && d!=c)`

Comment: @Simon It took me a while to understand that this was not a Mma question. I realized it after reading the answers and comments. Funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough information to provide a solution.

If the first statement is true, than the second is true. If the second statement is true, than the first is true.

It is just making a loop around and not proving anything.

Comment: you could say `C==D If and Only If A==B` and vice versa, but that's still not very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Only if C==D.

Not much use, I know, but I think it's all we can say with the information given.